# What is the best (free hosted) wiki for large non tech communities?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm searching for a (free hosted - would be awesome) wiki to power a large community of **NON techy users(~ 5K)** - like grandma and grandpa, so I'm asking your advice. I have some candidates (yes:I've already had a look on `wikimatrix.org`), but I'm eager to find out your opinion based on your experience. I have tried Wikia, but the searching mechanism doesn't behave as expected.

My requirements, based on their importance:

- Ease of utilization - WYSIWYG editor mandatory.
- Public for all
- Free hosting, ads accepted without messing the layout too much. Commercial products will be ultimately considered too.
- Forum support (direct or via plugin/extension)
- Block IP for malicious users
- File attachments support
- OpenId support (direct/ plugin)
- large community - if problems arise, a hand would be useful
- i18n support

Comment: what's the problem with Wikia's search? Otherwise this would be close to your requirements.

Comment: It does not search as it should. Eg: I have the text: The Lazy brown fox jumps high, and when I search "lazy" OR "laz" OR "Laz" it returns nothing...

Answer (score 1):

PBWorks is not bad.  I've heard a few ppl use Wikidot as well.

[PBWorks](http://pbworks.com/)

[Wikidot](http://www.wikidot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wikia.com/Wikia
or perhaps
http://www.wikispaces.com/